# Visual Basic - Gráficas Chart

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, tsql, visual-studio-2019

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    'Inserción de datos
    Try
        conex = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ElCopo.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        conex.Open()
        fecha = DateTime.Now
        querystring = "insert into TempCam1(Fecha,Temperatura) values(convert(datetime,'" & fecha & "', 103)," & temperatura.LeerEntero & ")"
        Dim Comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(querystring, conex)
        Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conex.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conex.Dispose()
    End Try
    'Consulta de datos
    Try
        conex = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ElCopo.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        conex.Open()
        dia()
        conex.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conex.Dispose()
    End Try
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub dia()
    Dim minDate As New DateTime(fecha.Year, fecha.Month, fecha.Day, fecha.Hour - 1, fecha.Minute, fecha.Second)
    Dim maxDate As New DateTime(fecha.Year, fecha.Month, fecha.Day, fecha.Hour, fecha.Minute, fecha.Second)
    'querystring = "select Fecha,Temperatura from TempCam1 where fecha between'" + minDate + "' AND '" + maxDate + "'"
    querystring = "select Fecha,Temperatura from TempCam1"
    Dim Comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(querystring, conex)
    reader = Comm.ExecuteReader()
    grafTemp.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    grafTemp.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    grafTemp.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MM HH:mm"
    grafTemp.Series(0).XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime
    'grafTemp.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate()
    'grafTemp.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate()
    grafTemp.Series(0).YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32
    While reader.Read

    grafTemp.Series(0).Points.
    AddY(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Temperatura")))
    End While
End Sub
```

Lo que pretendo hacer con este código es que me dibuje una gráfica en la que me dibuje vaya dibujando los valores que va teniendo la temperatura en la última hora. He probado de varias maneras, pero no me dibuja ese trazado. Si comento el asisX.minimun y el asisX.Maximun si que me dibuja la línea... no entiendo porque, y necesito marcarle esos valores al eje de las X... podríais ayudarme.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muchas gracias, señor gbianchi ;)

Comment: dicho esto, debo cerrarte la pregunta porque ayer preguntaste exactamente lo mismo, y el sitio no funciona replicando tu pregunta una y otra vez...